# php - check namespace in a condition

Tags: php, oop

I want my code to display "yes" if the scan function as the namespace "Imperium" as a parameter and displays "no" if it doesn't match Imperium

Here is what I tried:

```
namespace Imperium;
    class Soldier
    {
        public function getNameSpace()
        {
            return __NAMESPACE__;
        }
    }

namespace Chaos;
    class Soldier
    {
        public function getNameSpace()
        {
            return __NAMESPACE__;
        }
    }

class Scanner
{
    public function scan($Soldier)
    {
        if ($Soldier->getNameSpace() == "Imperium")
        {
            echo "yes\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no\n";
        }
    }
}

$scan = new Scanner();
$scan -> scan(Imperium);
```

ERROR I get

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNameSpace()**

Comment: Well, `Scanner::scan()` expects an object and you give it something string-ish.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, it sounds as though you are building some sort of dependency on the hierarchy of the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're checking `$Soldier->getNameSpace()` but you're not giving it a Soldier instance when you call `scan()`

```
namespace Imperium {
    class Soldier
    {
        public function getNameSpace()
        {
            return __NAMESPACE__;
        }
    }
}

namespace Chaos {
    class Soldier
    {
        public function getNameSpace()
        {
            return __NAMESPACE__;
        }
    }
}

namespace {
class Scanner
{
    public function scan($Soldier)
    {
        if ($Soldier->getNameSpace() == "Imperium")
        {
            echo "yes\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no\n";
        }
    }
}

    $soldier = new Imperium\Soldier();
    $scan = new Scanner();
    $scan->scan($soldier); /* Here giving it a soldier instance from imperium namespace */

}
```

Comment: like this? $scan -> scan("Imperium");

Comment: No. I edited my answer, but I think you're missing some OOP fundamentals.

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Chaos\Imperium\Soldier' not found

Comment: I updated my answer, refactorized the whole code, your scanner class was part of your chaos namespace, and i don't think that was intended. Pay attention to the namespace definition syntax, it avoids such mistakes. This code works, tested it out.